# How to alert and deleted a task using Sweet alert and vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am getting a confirm alert message by Sweet Alert but when I clicked the confirmed message, I am not able to delete the task.

```
methods: {
    confirmDelete: function(index) { //index is passed by the button
        //var self = this;
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            closeOnConfirm: true
        }, function(isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                this.contacts.splice(index, 1);
                swal(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                );

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably problem is `this` statment
try something like this:

```
    var self = this;
    function(isConfirm) {
              if(isConfirm){
                  self.contacts.splice(index, 1);
                  swal(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                  );

                  return true;
              }
              else{
                return false;
              }
```

Working version:
https://jsfiddle.net/jyfdh32g/

what i changed:
vue version to last stable - 1.0.25
confirm button action style from: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ sample.

why `$index` was not working?

> argument order updates: (value, index) in arr, (value, key, index) in
>   obj $index and $key deprecated

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2873

Comment: I am still not able to delete. Please find the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mithicher/5ur27pc7/2/ for complete code. Thanks ...

Comment: var $index is undefined in your v-for loop for some reason. I see that you're using vue 2.0 in beta version? Maybe this is the main reason for all the trouble.